# How can i set order for Eclipse Job execution?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jobs, job-scheduling

I have 2 methods contain selft jobs, for example

```
protected void method1(){
 String name=getName();//return name based on combobox selection
 Job job= new Job("first job"){
            @Override
            protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            someActions();
      }
   }
}

protected void method2(){
 String name=getName();//return name based on combobox selection
 Job job= new Job("second job"){
            @Override
            protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            someActions();
      }
   }
}
```

method1 and method2 can invoked seperated.With own progress bar

I have also some button to invoke both methods

```
 btnUpdate.addListener(SWT.MouseUp, new Listener() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                         method1();
                         method2();
                    }
     }
```

but this construction works incorrect becouse job from method2() start execute early then job from method1() finished. Also if i mark job from method1() as join then method2() will not start till the method1() execute, but progress bar doesn't displayed

How to make it work correctly?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prevent the 2 jobs from running simultanously by setting a job-rule:

```
public class Mutex implements ISchedulingRule {

        public boolean contains(ISchedulingRule rule) {
            return (rule == this);
        }

        public boolean isConflicting(ISchedulingRule rule) {
            return (rule == this);
        }

}// Mutex

public static final ISchedulingRule mutex = new Mutex();
```

for both of your jobs:

```
job.setRule(<your mutex instance>);
```

Make sure that both jobs use the same mutex-instance!

This should:

1. Prevent 2 jobs from running at the same time (if they both make use of the same rule)
2. Execute them in the order you schedule them

Btw.: You are not scheduling your jobs using `job.schedule()`, so actually they should not even be executed using the code you posted...

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for !